# not able to restore only data in mariadb?

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

Precisely said, I am trying to restore only data to a database but it does not work:

**Terminal Query Executing:**

```
mysqldump -u root -P port -p --no-create-info database < '/root/Documents/data'
```

**Output:**

```
xxx...


LOCK TABLES `table` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `table` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `table` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx
```

I am using `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.26-MariaDB`

If I do just `mysql -u root -p -P 15501 database < 'location/data'` it works but it replaces the structure too.

FYI: There is a column named `TITLE` in database structure but in `data.sql` it's called `NAME`

All replies are much appreciated!

Comment: You need to use `>` to redirect output, `<` is for input.

Comment: I've never heard of `mysqldump` using the wrong name for a column, I can't believe it would do that.

Comment: The file is just named `data`, not `data.sql`.

Comment: @barmar I am trying to restore data to the database. not back up from the database.

Comment: @Barmar I don't think the column name is the problem.

Comment: You don't use `mysqldump` to restore, you use `mysql`.

Comment: @barmar that is correct but still if you open `data` in a text editor it appears correctly.

Comment: What appears correctly? The column names in the dump file have to match the database schema.

Comment: @barmar then how do I use `mysql` to restore just data, and not the structure.

Comment: You have to use `--no-create-info` when you create the dump file, not when you're restoring it.

Comment: You can edit the dump file and remove all the `CREATE` commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `--no-create-info` option when creating the dump file, I don't think there's an option to ignore those statements when restoring.

If it's too late, you can edit the dump file and remove all the `DROP TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE` commands from the file.